# Function not returning any value

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

I'm making this function :

```
var Util = {
    clickOnCheck : function(evt){
        if($(evt.target).parent().hasClass("remainingSub")){
            var targetDiv = ".completedSub";
        } else if($(evt.target).parent().hasClass("completedSub")){
            targetDiv = ".remainingSub";
        }

        $(evt.target).parent()
                .fadeOut(200)
                    .parent()
                        .siblings(targetDiv)
                        .prepend($(evt.target).parent())
                        .end()
                    .end()
                .find(".optTrigger, .subHolder").toggle()
                .end()
            .fadeIn(100);

        return $(evt.target);
    }        
}
```

I'm making this because i want that behavior several times in several `click` events, also i want to get the event target to perform other operations with it after that function finishes its job.

But it seems that i don't get that object for some reason, i tried this :

```
$("#completedTasks").on("click", ".completedSub .checkButton", function(evt){
    var checkBtn = Util.clickOnCheck(evt);
    console.log(checkBtn);      
});
```

But when i run it i get nothing in the console log.

All what i want here is to get reference for the `.checkButton` button that being clicked.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Functions don't ignore a `return` statement. Yours returns the jQuery object. Are you sure the click handler is firing?

Comment: You know... you're declaring `targetDiv` twice in the same scope.

Comment: @elclanrs Ah, fixed now.

Comment: Redundant `var` declarations make no difference in outcome.

Comment: Your function successfully returns the jquery object of the event target for me as well.

Comment: @user1600680 Yes i'm sure, the effect caused by the function takes place, but still can't get reference for `.checkButton` button.

Comment: You won't have a direct reference. It will be at index `0` of the returned jQuery object. Is this all the code?

Comment: @user1600680 Yes, this is all the code.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ?

Comment: You say that "`i get nothing in the console log`" which suggests to me that your event handler is never firing. Even if `Util.clickOnCheck` returned nothing, you should still get some kind of output in your console.  What if you don't call the function at all in your event handler and just try a simple `alert` or `console.log`? Or can you post a minimal sample of HTML that this code should work on?